# Playing sound (.wav) file in MinGW c++ without opening an application

Tags: c++, mingw

I am working on a console application (C++, MinGW, Windows 7) that I want to play a media file without invoking a software.

Here's what I am looking for ... at the end of a batch file or a C++ program that takes many minutes to complete, I'd like to "beep" by playing the file "C:\Windows\Media\tada.wav".

I would like to use something like one of these system commands, but don't want Windows to open whatever .WAV application. It's one more window to close.

```
start "" "C:\Windows\Media\tada.wav"
"C:\Windows\Media\tada.wav"
```

Just like with any other Windows notification (new mail or Windows error), I'd like my computer to just play the file without opening any application.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: You can't play a sound file without opening an application to do so. You can _make_ an application, which doesn't show a window and plays a sound then closes, but you can't do it otherwise. The best you could achieve using only batch files would be to open softwarte, play the file then close it. Some software may allow you to open it windowed. If you're looking for advice on writing _the whole software to play a sound_ that's very far off-topic. Break your task down into small components and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your C++ code call the Win32 API [`PlaySound()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v%3Dvs.85)) function when needed.